# how to extract fields from mongo db change stream with C libbson

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

I have a bson_t "b" from a mongo db change stream which is printed like this by bson_as_canonical_extended_json :

```
{ "_id" : { "_data" : "825ECC4FEA0000002E2B022C0100296E5A10044A1DE2ECB8554397B8F
03E803FB80F1F463C5F6964003C3030313330323637000004" },   
"operationType" : "update",   
"clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1590448106, "i" : 46 } },   
"ns" : { "db" : "test", "coll" : "my_collection" },   
"documentKey" : { "_id" : "00130267" },   
"updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" },  
 "removedFields" : [  ] } }
```

I can get to the "documentKey" fields like this :

```
bson_iter_t iter;
if (bson_iter_init_find(&iter, b, "documentKey"))
bson_iter_t child;
if (bson_iter_recurse(&iter, &child))
{
    while (bson_iter_next(&child))
    {
        const bson_value_t *value = bson_iter_value(&child);
        printf("documentKey sub-key %s value %s\n", bson_iter_key(&child), (char*)value->value.v_utf8.str);
    }
}
```

which prints "_id" : "00130267"
how to access the fields of "updateDescription", are there any examples anywhere
this structure is not of my choosing it's from a mongo db change stream

the later answer by bauman is more rigorous, for me this works :

```
bson_iter_t iter1;
if (bson_iter_init_find(&iter1, b, "updateDescription")) // doc 
{
    bson_iter_t child1;
    if (bson_iter_recurse(&iter1, &child1))
    {
        while (bson_iter_next(&child1))// updatedFields doc
        {
            bson_iter_t child2;
            bson_iter_recurse(&child1, &child2);
            while (bson_iter_next(&child2))
            {
                const bson_value_t *value = bson_iter_value(&child2);
                printf("updateDescription arr %s value %s\n", bson_iter_key(&child2), (char*)value->value.v_utf8.str);// key and value of the array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pretty much the same as you did for `documentKey` just use `updateDescription` and then `updatedFields`.

Comment: updatedFields should be an object of {fieldname: new value}

Comment: so I thought, the updatedFields "doc" contains an array, I'd need to access elements with "0" "1" ..., bearing in mind this structure is formatted like this by mongo db and it could be useful to others, are there any examples how to access an array with libbson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to descend twice, first into the outer document and then into the inner document.

[libbson documentation is really good.  props to the mongodb staff](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/parsing.html?highlight=find#parsing-and-iterating-bson-documents)

here is a full example

```
#include <bson.h>


void descending_to_updateDescription(bson_t *b){
    bson_iter_t change_iter;
    if (bson_iter_init_find(&change_iter, b, "updateDescription"))
    {
        bson_iter_t desired_field;
        if (bson_iter_recurse(&change_iter, &desired_field))
        {
           // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
           //        (key)          ^   (value)
           // pointer is now here   |  (at the beginning of the document

           // confirm the (value) is type DOCUMENT as we expect (containing  keys, "updateFields" and "removedFields"
           if BSON_ITER_HOLDS_DOCUMENT(&change_iter){
               while (bson_iter_next(&desired_field))
               {
                   // printing the outer key (expect 2, shown below)
                   printf("%s\n", bson_iter_key(&desired_field));
                   // first loop
                   // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                   //                             (key)       ^   (value) -- another document
                   // pointer is now here   ----------------- |
                   //
                   // next loop
                   // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                   //                                                                                                     (key)     ^   (value) - a list
                   // pointer is now waaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyy ovvvvvveeeeerrr  here  --------------------------------------------------- |
                   // next loop
                   // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                   //                                                                                                                      ^
                   // pointer is now waaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyy ovvvvvveeeeerrr  here  ---------------------------------------------------------- | (end of document
                   // iter_next returns false, because no other keys in the outer dict


                   // descend into the next level down
                   bson_iter_t changefields_iter;
                   // SUPER IMPORTANT, recurese from desired_field, not from the original change iter!
                   if (bson_iter_recurse(&desired_field, &changefields_iter)){
                       // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                       //                             (key)         ^   (value) - a document
                       // pointer is now here  -------------------- |
                       // expect update fields to hold a documnet, and removeFields to hold a list, skip processing remove fields
                       while (bson_iter_next(&changefields_iter)) {
                           // first loop
                           // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                           //                                               (key)  ^   (value) - a string in this example
                           // pointer is now here  --------------------------------|
                           // second  loop
                           // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                           //                                                                       (key)  ^   (value) - a string in this example
                           // pointer is now here  --------------------------------------------------------|
                           // third  loop
                           // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
                           //                                                                                            ^
                           // pointer is now here  ----------------------------------------------------------------------| (end of document)

                           // Example looks like we expect string values, so check for it
                           if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_UTF8(&changefields_iter)){
                               uint32_t length; // iterating the string object can give you length, we don't need it though because we're not strncopying
                               printf(
                                       "\tKey: %s \t Value: %s\n",
                                       bson_iter_key(&changefields_iter),
                                       bson_iter_utf8(&changefields_iter, &length)
                                       );
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    // just setting up
    char * json_data = "{ \"_id\" : { \"_data\" : \"825ECC4FEA0000002E2B022C0100296E5A10044A1DE2ECB8554397B8F03E803FB80F1F463C5F6964003C3030313330323637000004\" }, \"operationType\" : \"update\", \"clusterTime\" : { \"$timestamp\" : { \"t\" : 1590448106, \"i\" : 46 } }, \"ns\" : { \"db\" : \"test\", \"coll\" : \"my_collection\" }, \"documentKey\" : { \"_id\" : \"00130267\" }, \"updateDescription\" : { \"updatedFields\" : { \"0x000F\" : \"25.006001\", \"0x0010\" : \"24.976000\" }, \"removedFields\" : [  ] } }" ;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_t      *b;
    b = bson_new_from_json ((uint8_t*)json_data, -1, &error);
    descending_to_updateDescription(b);
    bson_destroy(b);
    b = NULL; // explicit nulled in case this is extended later
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output

```
updatedFields
    Key: 0x000F      Value: 25.006001
    Key: 0x0010      Value: 24.976000
removedFields

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The important fact is that second descent.

When you find and recurse into updateDescription, you need to descend again into the updatedFields/updatedFields documents as well to go print them off.

Also, if you really just want to check the "updateFields" you can always turn your explicit while loop into an implicit (library performed) while loop use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and the [find_descendant](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/parsing.html?highlight=find#finding-fields-using-dot-notation) function. Your code looks cleaner, but you're not saving any performance by doing it, the library is doing the same loop you did in the above example

```
#include <bson.h>
void descending_direct_to_updateFields(bson_t *b){
    bson_iter_t change_iter;
    bson_iter_t updateFields_iter;
    // use the find_descendant function
    if (bson_iter_init(&change_iter, b) && bson_iter_find_descendant(&change_iter, "updateDescription.updatedFields", &updateFields_iter)) {
        // "updateDescription" : { "updatedFields" : { "0x000F" : "25.006001", "0x0010" : "24.976000" }, "removedFields" : [  ] }
        //                                  (key)  ^   (value) - document with 2 keys
        // pointer is now here  -------------------|
        printf("%s\n", "updateDescription.updatedFields"); // just print because you looked for it
        if BSON_ITER_HOLDS_DOCUMENT(&updateFields_iter){
            bson_iter_t desired_field;
            bson_iter_recurse(&updateFields_iter, &desired_field);
            while (bson_iter_next(&desired_field)) {
                if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_UTF8(&desired_field)) {
                    uint32_t length; // iterating the string object can give you length, we don't need it though because we're not strncopying
                    printf(
                            "\tKey: %s \t Value: %s\n",
                            bson_iter_key(&desired_field),
                            bson_iter_utf8(&desired_field, &length)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    // just setting up
    char * json_data = "{ \"_id\" : { \"_data\" : \"825ECC4FEA0000002E2B022C0100296E5A10044A1DE2ECB8554397B8F03E803FB80F1F463C5F6964003C3030313330323637000004\" }, \"operationType\" : \"update\", \"clusterTime\" : { \"$timestamp\" : { \"t\" : 1590448106, \"i\" : 46 } }, \"ns\" : { \"db\" : \"test\", \"coll\" : \"my_collection\" }, \"documentKey\" : { \"_id\" : \"00130267\" }, \"updateDescription\" : { \"updatedFields\" : { \"0x000F\" : \"25.006001\", \"0x0010\" : \"24.976000\" }, \"removedFields\" : [  ] } }" ;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_t      *b;
    b = bson_new_from_json ((uint8_t*)json_data, -1, &error);
    descending_direct_to_updateFields(b);
    bson_destroy(b);
    b = NULL; // explicit nulled in case this is extended later
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output

```
updateDescription.updatedFields
    Key: 0x000F      Value: 25.006001
    Key: 0x0010      Value: 24.976000
```

*Stack overflow defaults to a ridiculously over-protective license for these answers. To the extent allowed, I place all code and words within this answer into the public domain.  Where public domain is not allowed or recognized, the code and words is licensed under the same license as libbson itself.*